# Predefined squareroot function without using sqrt() from math.h in C

Tags: c, windows, math

**Homework question:**

- Cygwin GNU **GDB**
- Cygwin GNU **GCC**

Attempting to establish the length of the **hypotenuse** C from the square root of **A** power of 2 and **B** power of 2.

**Example** input:

Enter the length of two sides of a right-angled triangle: 2.25  8.33

**Answer:**

The length of the hypotenuse is: 8.628523

- **Question:** when I specify the same input as above, the result is not the **same** - output is **19.84.9596**

Full **code** below:

```
float squareRoots(float *s)
{
    float cx;
    float nx;
    float e;

    cx = 1;
    nx = (cx +*s/cx)/2;
    e = nx - cx;
    cx = nx;

    if (e*e > 0.001)
    {
        nx = (cx +*s/cx)/2;
        return nx;
    } else {
        return nx;
    }
}

float hypotenuse(float *a, float *b)
{
    float c;
    //raise a to power of 2
    *a = (*a * *a);
    *b = (*b * *b);
    //add a and b
    float y = *a + *b;
    c = squareRoots(&y);

    return c;
}


int main()
{
    float x,y;

    printf("Enter the length of two sides of a right-angled triangle:");
    scanf("%f %f", &x, &y);
    float k=hypotenuse(&x,&y);

    printf("The length of the hypotenuse is: %f", k);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you passing pointers to floats instead of passing by value?

Comment: @Andrew - I agree; indeed, given that the code is modifying the values too, it is pretty horrible.

Answer (score 6):

The square root algorithm you're (supposed to be?) using is called [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).  Your if statement should be a while loop.

Replace

```
if (e*e > 0.001)
{
        nx = (cx +*s/cx)/2;
        return nx;
} else {
        return nx;
}
```

with a while loop that iteratively does the same, but includes recalculating e.

I would give you the working code, but you said this is homework.  If you can't get it to work, post your new code and I'll be happy to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @Bill: It's usually called 'Newton–Raphson', at least in most of the refs I've seen :)

Comment: Cannot believe I didn't notice this...

Comment: @Atklin: If you've taken a numerical methods course recently, you should have.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Want a super-duper square root implementation?  Check out [John Carmack's magic square root from Quake III](http://www.codemaestro.com/reviews/9).

```
float Q_rsqrt( float number )
{
  long i;
  float x2, y;
  const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

  x2 = number * 0.5F;
  y  = number;
  i  = * ( long * ) &y;  // evil floating point bit level hacking
  i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 ); // what the ****?
  y  = * ( float * ) &i;
  y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) ); // 1st iteration
  // y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) ); // 2nd iteration, this can be removed

  #ifndef Q3_VM
  #ifdef __linux__
    assert( !isnan(y) ); // bk010122 - FPE?
  #endif
  #endif
  return y;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use the described algorithm...

Comment: Note that this is actually the inverse square root function, so you have to 1/x the result to get the square root.

Comment: The "wtf" part will become clear after reading the IEEE spec and figuring out how to write sqrt in terms of log2. Also, papers have been written about the constant used.

Comment: Also, in contrast to common belief, the constant isn't the initial guess. The (i >> 1) part does that plenty. The only thing the constant does is adjust the initial guess.

Answer (score 0):

I make the answer 8.628522469, i.e. 8.628522.

Comment: Using the same code? Strange - I'm compiling under cygwin using GNU GDB...

Comment: No, you are not compiling with gdb. You're probably compiling with gcc.